# How to use jQuery in code from ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with parsing data from ajax callback

This code:

```
$.get( "test.php", function( html) {
  var data = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
  var name = $(data' #name').val();

}, "html" );
```

Not working ,but this:

```
$.get( "test.php", function( html) {
  var data = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
  var name = data.getElementById('name').value;

}, "html" );
```

Works without problem

Why ?

Comment: try `var name = $(data).find('#name').val();`

Comment: Please describe what you mean by `Not working`. Include all error details. Keep in mind that no one can see your screen but you so for all we know `Not working` means your computer literally caught on fire.

Comment: `$(data' #name')` clearly isn't valid javascript syntax...

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax error in `$(data' #name')` that you are missing a `,`

One the other not you can just simply do `$('#name', html).val();`